# Synchronizing time between two points

Tags: time, algorithms

Suppose we have two points on earth, A and B, both with clock.

Suppose we can send some information between points, with a random delay:
$$
min < delay < max
$$

($min$ theoretically exists because of speed of light, on practice it is 5-10 milliseconds, $max$ is for symmetry)

**What is the best precision, at which we can theoretically sync clock in these points?**

**Is it true, that if each message comes with an exact, known delay value, we can sync the time without any error?**

*My thoughts on the question:*

1. If the delay is known:

   > We can receive message `(sendTime, delay)` and immediately add local `recvTime` in it. So, to get `remoteTime` at any local moment `t` we can do
   >   $$
   > \Delta = sendTime + delay - recvTime\\
   > remoteTime = t + \Delta\\
   > error = 0
   > $$
2. If the delay is unknown:

   > We can receiveMessage `(sendTime)`, add local `recvTime` and send it back.
   >
   > Later, other side recieves `(sendTime, recvTime)` at time `t`. It can:
   >   $$
   > 2*min < tripTime = t - sendTime < 2 * max\\
   > estDelay = tripTime/2\\
   > \Delta = recvTime - (sendTime + estDelay)\\
   > remoteTime = t + \Delta\\
   > error \sim estDelay
   > $$
   >   We can simultaneously send such messages and use only ones with small $estDelay$, so the error would be close to $min$.

BONUS: **What if the clock at this points go with some slight error?**

Comment: On a practical note: see [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) which can synchronise clocks thousands of kilometers apart to accuracies of a few milliseconds. I believe it is the jitter and not the latency which limits this.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick seems like it heavily relies on symmetrical from/to delays, which is not true in general case.
My question applies more to theoretical precision limits.

Comment: [VLBI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very-long-baseline_interferometry) requires nanosecond accuracy between stations to work.

Comment: Rustem Mustafin: "_What is the best precision [...] so the error would be [...]_" -- You might consider to ask about ["accuracy", instead of "_precision_"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision); thereby defining (more comprehensively than presently) what you mean by "_error_". Also: "_Suppose we have two points on earth, A and B, both with clock._" -- Is supposed/required that each clock is **good** (i.e. with $t$ values assigned proportional to the durations between indications)? Are the "_two points on earth_" supposed to be at rest to each other, or only rigid to each other?

Comment: p.s. After now actually having skimmed through [the wikipedia article I had linked in my above comment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) I should rather recommend to consider asking about "trueness", instead "_precision_".

Comment: @user12262 actually what I mean is to maximize precison, which is proportional to error^(-1), which is proportional to difference between actual time and estimated time.
Sorry, in case my terminology differs from established in this area.
Anyway, the main question is -- does this random latency actually limit us in the precision, or is there some way to overcome it?

Comment: @Rustem Mustafin: "_to maximize precison, which is proportional to error^(-1), which is proportional to difference between actual time and estimated time._" -- Alright; so how would you define "_actual time_" (as "reference value", or "true value") in the first place? (I'd expect that this involves some consideration of "simultaneity"; which is why I'm mainly interested in your question.)

Comment: @user12262 this is simple. Suppose, we are at point B. In the simplest way, `syncing` time here is getting to know the difference between our local time and time at point A. In previous comment, I named `actual time` -- time at point A, and `estimated time` -- our estimation of time at point A (remeber, we're at B).

Comment: @Rustem Mustafin: "_[...] In previous comment, I named `actual time` -- time at point A, and `estimated time` -- our estimation of time at point A_" -- It's certainly right and important that you gave specific distinct names to the specific distinct quantities that need to be considered; and that you even stated some equations in your question which relate those quantities to each other. But that's still not enough (for me, anyways) to find an answer to your question; I'd need some more detailed definition about how at least one of those ought to be measured at all, at least in principle.

Comment: @user12262 I cannot see any troubles here. For example, after syncing, clock can be moved to a single place, from points A and B, where the difference between them will be clearly observable.

Comment: @user12262 this is how you measure error. One proposition of syncing is in the post itself. What You could also do is add a clone of clock A in the point B, what could let you do the syncing process and know the exact difference continously.

Comment: @Rustem Mustafin: "_For example, after syncing, clock can be moved to a single place, from points A and B, where the difference between them will be clearly observable._" -- My problem is in this case that you seem to be considering just 2 single clocks (one initially "_at A_"; the other one initially "_at B_"). But there are very many clocks imaginable initially; many of them may be initially "_in synch_"; and having all "_moved to a single place_" their indications may be (pairwise) utterly different from each other. So: which only 2 clock among all clocks imaginable should be considered ??

Comment: @user12262 Pick all imaginable clock. Pick any of them, name it `A`. Pick another clock, in a different place, name it `B`. There you go. Actually, from the point of view of random initial selection of clock, it does not matter.

Comment: Rustem Mustafin: "_[...] Pick any of them, name it `A`_" -- Fair enough. "_Pick another clock, in a different place, [...] `B`._" -- In your formulas above there appears the quantity (or number) "$tripTime$". I worry about whether there's any requirement or implication relating "$tripTime$ from `A` to `B`" and "$tripTime$ from `B` to `A`". Also: If I pick yet another clock `F` for **the same place as** `B` (the same "small hand", the same "indications" which were involved in identifying clock `B`), but if "$tripTime$ from `A` to `F`" and "$tripTime$ from `A` to `B`" are not equal, then what?